# Greasemonkey script to alert when specific text is not found on page not working?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I wrote a script to alert me when a certain page doesn't contain the phrase "Sorry, keep trying" so that I wouldn't have to actually check each page...

This seems like a simple little script... but it's alerting even when the text IS found on the page... what am I doing wrong here?

```
if(document.body.innerHTML != "Sorry, keep trying"){
  window.alert("Check this page!");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script just checks the inner html of the body is == "Sorry, keep trying". So the only page that wouldn't alert the message would be a page that looked like

```
<html> 
  <body>Sorry, keep trying</body> 
</html>
```

Try this:

```
if(document.body.innerHTML.indexOf("Sorry, keep trying") == -1){
  alert("Check this page!");
}
```

Comment: @KatCox I added a script that will alert when the string isn't present on the page.